# Is there an AWS quota on API endpoint amount of data returned

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

I have an amplify app, that uses Cognito Users Pool for auth. One of the queries is for fetching 'estimations' from AppSync API.
The problem that I face is when I try to fetch all estimations unfortunately the endpoint returns only the first 18 entries of 130 entries that I can see that exist in the DinamoDB table.

The only indication that I have, so far, is when I go in the DinamoDB interface and go to the table, I can see there the engine also fetches the table documents in chunks, as you can see on the picture below. First 18 documents are fetched, than 35... than 52... ans so on until 130.

[image]

So, basically my frontend always shows only this first 18 entries from the table...

I don't know if there is probably some quota in how much data can certain endpoint response with, because there is preety much a lot of data in the configs property of a document.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a limit of how much data you get by default get from the Amplify generated query resolver without pagination: https://medium.com/open-graphql/create-a-multiuser-graphql-crud-l-app-in-10-minutes-with-the-new-aws-amplify-cli-and-in-a-few-73aef3d49545

> By default the Amplify CLI configured resources on AWS AppSync will limit the scan operation to 10 items, that means DynamoDB will read 10 items from the table

You should add the pagination functionality to your Amplify solution to be able to paginate over all records - https://docs.amplify.aws/guides/api-graphql/graphql-pagination/q/platform/js

Comment: @Milian actually the problem is not with pagination, since I have tried to remedy this by adding pagination, and yet the problem existed.